# Draw solutions of $y'=2x\sqrt{(1-y^2)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=2x\sqrt{(1-y^2)}$

I tried to draw some solutions of this slopes field (the red lines) , but I cant get how to draw it.

I know that there is no common points between two different solutions and there is no intersection.

[image]

I am really don't know how I supposed to draw the solutions by the slopes field.

I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: Your upper red curve is a decent start. A solution can never actually reach the $y=1$ orange dotted line, so it must be a horizontal asymptote of every solution.

Comment: Hm, now I'm not sure about reaching $y=1$.

Comment: @aschepler $y=\pm 1$ are actually (constant) solutions.

Comment: @PierreCarre $y=1$ is the only solution when $y(0)=1$ ? and  $y=-1$ is the only solution when $y(0)=-1$? (Picard-Lindelöf theorem)

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, but so is $y=\sin(x^2)$ on $x^2 \leq \pi/2$ with $y=1$ on $x^2 \geq \pi/2$. I guess something about the non-intersection theorem isn't satisfied?

Comment: Ah, right. The formula is not Lipschitz continuous, so Picard–Lindelöf doesn't apply in a region including $y=\pm 1$.

Comment: @aschepler yes,l'm just pointing out that it is not true that "A solution can never actually reach the $y=1$..."

Comment: @PierreCarre I meant to say a solution with $-1 < y_0 < 1$ would never reach $y=\pm 1$, but yes, this is also false: they all do reach $y=+1$ at finite $x$ values.

Comment: When $y(0)=1$, $y(x)=1$ is the only solution. When $y(0)=-1$, there are many solutions; one is $y = -\cos(x^2)$ if $x^2 \leq \pi$ and $y = 1$ if $x^2 \geq \pi$. I think we could characterize all these solutions in terms of the interval $a < x < b$ where $y(x)=-1$, given $a$ is a non-positive real number or "$-\infty$" and $b$ is a non-negative real number or "$+\infty$".

Comment: @aschepler $y'=2x\cdot\sqrt{1-y^{2}}\implies\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}=2xdx\implies\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}=\int2x+C\implies arcsin(y)=x^{2}+C $ by using $y(0)=-1$ $\implies C=arcsin(-1)$.

Then $y=sin(x+arcsin(-1))$ I cant see another solution pass in $(0,-1) $except $y=-1.$

Comment: Actually $y = \sin(x^2+\arcsin(-1))=-\cos(x^2)$ is not a solution for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, only for $x \in [-\sqrt{\pi}, \sqrt{\pi}]$. Instead we have a full solution: $$y=\begin{cases} -\cos(x^2) & x^2 \leq \pi \\ 1 & x^2 > \pi \end{cases}$$

Comment: And you already gave two solutions for $y(0)=-1$. For more, pick any $a \leq 0$ and $b \geq 0$, and we get a solution $$y= \begin{cases} 1 & x \leq -\sqrt{a^2+\pi} \\ -\cos(x^2-a^2) & -\sqrt{a^2+\pi}<x<a \\ -1 & a \leq x \leq b \\ -\cos(x^2-b^2) & b<x<\sqrt{b^2+\pi} \\ 1 & x \geq \sqrt{b^2+\pi} \end{cases}$$

Comment: @aschepler $-\cos(x^2)$ is not a solution for all $x \in \mathbb(R)$ since the $\sqrt{1-y^{2}}$ ? cant see it

Comment: It's not a solution for all $x$ because the derivative gets the wrong sign in places: If $y=-\cos(x^2)$ then when $\pi < x^2 < 2\pi$, $dy/dx = 2x \sin(x^2) = -2x \sqrt{1-y^2}$ which doesn't match the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the slope field and some solutions:
[image]

Why this was expected?
Because $2x\sqrt{(1-y^2)}>0$ for all $x>0$ and $-1<y<1$, so all solutions must be strictly increasing there. Also $2x\sqrt{(1-y^2)}<0$ for all $x<0$ and $-1<y<1$, so all solutions must be strictly decreasing there.

Comment: These solutions on just finite $x$ intervals could be extended to solutions for all real $x$ by joining the endpoints to constant $y=+1$ lines.

Answer (score 1):

From the equation, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} = 2xdx  &\iff \int_{y_0}^y \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}= x^2-x_0^2\\ &\iff\arcsin(y)-\arcsin{y_0}=x^2-x_0^2\tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Thus, from $(1)$ the solution is
$$y = \sin(x^2+\arcsin{y_0}-x_0^2) \tag{2}$$
for $x$ satisfying the condition $$-\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin{y_0}+x_0^2\leq x^2 \leq \frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin{y_0}+x_0^2  \tag{3}$$

From $(2)$ we can plot the solutions in the region $\mathcal{D}$ defined by $(3)$

**Example**, for $(x_0,y_0) = (2, \frac{1}{2})$, the region $\mathcal{D}$ is
$$\mathcal{D} = \{x| -\frac{2}{3}\pi+4\le x^2 \le  \frac{1}{3}\pi+4 \} = \{x| \sqrt{-\frac{2}{3}\pi+4} \le x \le  \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\pi+4} \}$$

[image]

Comment: The solutions are not unique!

Comment: Note that all solutions are strictly increasing when $x>0$...

Comment: There are certainly not real solutions with $y<-1$ or $y>1$.

Comment: @aschepler I think the solution is unique.

Comment: @DiegoSantos Yes, the solution now is now strictly increase in the region $\mathcal{D}$

Comment: Yes, the solution for $(x_0,y_0)=(2,\frac{1}{2})$ is unique on $\mathcal{D}$. The only differentiable extension to that on $x>\sqrt{\pi/3+4}$ is the constant function $y=1$. But there are multiple differentiable extensions on $x<\sqrt{-2\pi/3+4}$, including constant $y=-1$, or $y=-1$ on $[0,\sqrt{-2\pi/3+4}]$ joined with $y=-\cos(x^2)$ on $[-\sqrt{\pi},0]$ and $y=1$ on $(\infty,-\sqrt{\pi})$.